# Wirless 802.11g driver needed, but no device details available

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, connection, wireless-networking

I recently formatted my XP machine and installed Windows Server 2008 R2.
I had some trouble getting the configuration right for wireless internet (as it is disabled by default). However, after fixing all the configurations, it still did not work.

It seems the driver for 802.11g WLAN is missing. However, no device details (manufacturer, productcodes, device type) is available.

Is there any way to get my WLAN working? I even opened the physical machine, but couldn't find anything. It is an old Medion set, bought about 6 years ago. I couldn't find any service support on the Medion site (probably expired?)

Comment: I think this question is best asked on superuser.com - my first thought would be Windows 2008r2 drivers for a 6 year old machine may simply not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try : http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Unknown-Device-Identifier.shtml
Then look for generic drivers from vendor.

*BTW, what is the point of installing recent Windows Server 2008 R2 on 6 year old box? Nothing serious, right?*

Comment: well no. I want to learn more about servers. Business partners exclusively use 2008(R2) machines.

Comment: I moved the machine to the router, got internet now at the cable...

Comment: however, thanks for the identifier! I found a driver for vista and windows 7, but I got a strange error that said I had to install the windows autoconfig service on manual. I did, but the error kept going.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 R2 is 64-bit only, so will require a 64 bit driver for any hardware attached to it. Since this machine is about 6 years old, I think you'll struggle to find a 64 bit driver even if you do manage to identify the hardware.